# Erro ao conectar SQL server

Tags: sql-server

Olá, baixei o SQL Server Express 2014 with tools do site da Microsoft. Fiz a instalação porém quando vou iniciar da erro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Descrição do erro:

```
TITLE: Connect to Server
------------------------------

Cannot connect to willian.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

 Erro de rede ou específico à instância ao estabelecer conexão com o SQL     Server. O servidor não foi encontrado ou não estava acessível. Verifique se o nome da instância está correto e se o SQL Server está configurado para permitir conexões remotas. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Não foi possível abrir uma conexão com o SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)

 For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=2&LinkId=20476

 ------------------------------

 O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

Procurei em alguns locais mas não achei nada que resolve-se e já tentei reinstalar

Comment: O serviço do SQL Server está rodando? Em caso afirmativo tem certeza que a instância se chama willian?

Comment: Aparentemente o serviço está rodando sim. Então como verifico a instância? Nunca utilizei o SQL Server eu só fui instalando não alterei nada

Comment: @cartoni entrei no CMD digitei SQLCMD -L para descobrir a instância e só tem uma mesmo com meu nome WILLIAN

Comment: Abra o prompt de comando e execute: SQLCMD -L

Comment: Está rodando na sua máquina mesmo, correto? Se sim, é tudo muito estranho, mas você poderia verificar se tem alguma coisa de firewall bloqueando, embora eu ache difícil, já que se trata de localhost.

Comment: Sim na minha máquina. Será que é o serviço então? Tem que aparecer algo tipo SQLWILLIAN ?

Comment: Só do SQLCMD -L ter retornado a instancia WILLIAN é sinal de que o serviço está rodando. Mas vc pode conferir, vá no Gerenciador de Tarefas e procure um processo que se chama sqlservr.exe.

Comment: Está lá aparentemente normal, uê

Comment: Ultima dica: troque WILLIAN por localhost (ou pelo nome do seu computador). No mais, o máximo que consigo te ajudar é te linkar a este documento: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2102.how-to-troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine.aspx

Comment: Não alterou nada, continua o erro. Mas viu vou dar uma buscada aqui. De qualquer forma muito obrigado @cartoni

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solucionei da seguinte forma:**

1. verificar se o serviço está funcionando

   > SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) - iniciá-lo.

   2ª ir no menu iniciar > paínel de controle > ferramentas
   administrativas > fontes de dados ODBC

   3ª adicionar um novo > selecionar "SQL SERVER"

   4ª colocar seu nome, descrição, e nome do servidor

   Observação: Nome do servidor segue um padrão por exemplo no meu caso
   WILLIAN\SQLEXPRESS

   Nome do usuário do computador.

   5ª Deixar autenticação com windows 6ª Selecionar a primeira checkbox
   "master". 7ª concluir > testar fontes de dados > ok > ok

   8ª Abra o SQLSERVER em nome do servidor, abrir combobox e selecionar
   o que foi criado e iniciar.

**Vídeo explicativo:** [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zB9c_oq7uyQ)

Comment: Então você está usando uma instancia nomeada e por isso deve fazer WILLIAN\SQLEXPRESS.

Comment: @cantoni Isso. Obrigado por acrescentar :)